# JSF 2.0 with Expression is a method error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2

I have this line in my jsf page

```
<h:dataTable value="#{customer.getCustomerList()}"
```

and in my bean I have

```
public List<Customer> getCustomerList(){
        return customerBo.findAllCustomer();
    }
```

I am using JSF 2.0 with Eclipse Helios with servlet 2.5 and when I validate I am getting

```
Expression must be a value expression but is a method expression
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{customer.customerList}"
```

The `value` attribute of your `h:dataTable` expects a value expression, not a method expression. You have to create a property called `customerList` in your `#{customer}` managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private List<Customer> custormerList= new ArrayList<Customer>();

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> cust){
       this.customerList = cust;
    }
    public List<Customer> getCustomerList(){
        return customerBo.findAllCustomer();
    }
}
```

[Refer to the h:dataTable tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html)

Answer (score 15):

I have a similar problem, despite the fact i was doing right, like PermGenError posted. I had this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.registry}"></h:commandButton>
```

And i got error: **Expression must be a method expression but is a value expression**

In my Bean, there was:

```
class Bean{

    Registry registry = new Registry();

    public Registry getRegistry() {
        return registry;
    }
}
```

Reason of this message is that Eclipse doesn't recognize that this is actually method calling, in JSF manner, and give this message like an error. This can be turned off on this way:

**Window/ Preferences/ Web/ JavaServer Faces Tools/ Validation/ Type Assignment Problems/ Method expression expected**

change to **Warning** or **Ignore**

I hope this will help someone!